# why does invoke restmethod takes more bandwidth load compared to view source in chrome?

Tags: powershell

```
$HTML = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09M4B71YS/' -UseBasicParsing
>> $HTML -match '<span class="a-price-whole">(?<test>.*)<span>'
>> $Matches
>> $HTML.length
>> $Matches= $null ,$HTML = $null
True
True

Name                           Value
----                           -----
test                           785<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">00</sp...
0                              <span class="a-price-whole">785<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span><span cla...
1865728
```

with chrome its not that
[![with chrome its not that ][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMRYn.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWatr.png

[![but with ps this crap happens][2]][2]

am I writing the ps code wrong I'm not a programmer or trying to do anything fancy just checking on the price of stuff

Comment: don't try to compare that visually. you can query the page almost exactly like ms edge would do. if you start developer tools in ms edge with "F12" then open your desired page you can scroll up to the network tab and the event that queried your page. right click on that and click "copy >" and "copy as powershell". Paste this code in PowerShell to get same UserAgent, cookies for your query. if you rerun the query and look at "RawContentLength" you will see this page is not always the same size. But in general if you fix your regex you are on a way that might work for you.

Comment: Can there be a lower bandwidth by capping the size of the string? I googled and can't find answers to limiting size or limiting the restmethod except redirects but it still give the length around 1803351